# Llama a la función de forma recursiva

Tags: java, array, recursión

tengo un ejercicio de recursividad en el que tengo que imprimir una matriz, a este problema solo hay que agregar una sola linea para terminar la recursividad pero no tengo idea :c esa linea se agregar despues del comentario donde indica que se llama la funcion.

Aquí esta el código

```java
    public void imprimirMatrizRecursivo(int[][] m, int i, int j) {
        //Se imprime el contenido de la casilla m[i][j]
        System.out.print(m[i][j] + " ");
         if (i != m.length - 1 || j != m[i].length - 1) {
            //Si ya se llegó al final de la fila
            if (j == m[i].length - 1) {
                //Se avanza a la siguiente fila
                i++;
                //Se reinicia el índice de la columna
                j = 0;
                //Se imprime salto de linea para darle formato
                System.out.println();
            }
             else {
                //Se pasa a la siguiente columna
                j++;
            }
            //Se llama a la función de forma recursiva:

        }

    }
```

Ojala puedan ayudarme soy nuevo en esto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el `if` y en el `else` se va incrementando los indices, pasando por el `if` o por el `else` debe ser llamado asi mismo (recursividad) asi que debes invocar a la misma funcion:   `imprimirMatrizRecursivo(m, i, j);`

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int [][] matrix ={{6,7,5}, {3, 8, 4}, {1,0,2}, {9,5,2}};
        imprimirMatrizRecursivo(matrix, 0 ,0);
  }




  public static void imprimirMatrizRecursivo(int[][] m, int i, int j) {
        System.out.print(m[i][j] + " ");
         if (i != m.length - 1 || j != m[i].length - 1) {
            if (j == m[i].length - 1) {
                i++;
                j = 0;
            }
             else {
                j++;
            }
            imprimirMatrizRecursivo(m, i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfecto! Gracias! :D

Answer (score 1):

Después de tu comentario debes de llamar a la misma función que en la que estás, pasando nuevamente los parámetros correspondientes, es decir:

```
imprimirMatrizRecursivo(m, i, j);
```

Dentro del método que tienes acciones que cambian el valor de las variables `i` y `j`, por lo mismo lo que pasa por parámetro no es lo mismo que le llega al método cuando este es llamado recursivamente.

---

El código quedaría así:

```java
public void imprimirMatrizRecursivo(int[][] m, int i, int j) {
        //Se imprime el contenido de la casilla m[i][j]
        System.out.print(m[i][j] + " ");
         if (i != m.length - 1 || j != m[i].length - 1) {
            //Si ya se llegó al final de la fila
            if (j == m[i].length - 1) {
                //Se avanza a la siguiente fila
                i++;
                //Se reinicia el índice de la columna
                j = 0;
                //Se imprime salto de linea para darle formato
                System.out.println();
            }
             else {
                //Se pasa a la siguiente columna
                j++;
            }
            //Se llama a la función de forma recursiva:
            imprimirMatrizRecursivo(m, i, j);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Gracias c: era tan fácil xd